# make windows 10 recognize php 7

Tags: php, windows-10

I tried to install PHP 7 without any local server but the windows doesn't recognize PHP 7  usually i use wamp server
I downloaded PHP 7 in my local folder C:\php

This is PHP directory:
[image]

If I open a command prompt and type

```
cd C:\php
php -v
```

The output of the command shows me

> PHP 7.1.9

Then I added in the Environment Variables Path  `C:\php`.
and the only thing in Environment Variables relevant to PHP is `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25`
Now if I open a new command prompt and type

```
php -v
```

The output is still

> PHP 5.6.25

where I would expect PHP 7.1.9.

I need the version to be php 7 for using Laravel 5.5.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What web server are you running?

Comment: Is the path to php 5.6 still in your environment variable as well?

Comment: Sometimes a computer logoff/restart is the only way to make a PATH variable change take place.

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: yes , i really need a solution,

Comment: which web server are you using? apache or nginx?